# Casting a Parent to its Generic Child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following setup:

```
public class Child<T>: BaseClass
{
    public T Value;
}

public class IntChild: Child<int> { }

public class BoolChild: Child<bool> { }

public class FloatChild: Child<float> { }

public class MyProgram
{
    public BaseClass Source;

    public void SetValue(object val)
    {
        // I want to do something like the following
        // ((Child) Source).Value = (val.GetType()) val;

        // Instead, I have to do it like this
        string temp = val.ToString();
        switch (Source.GetType())  
        {
            case "IntChild":
                ((IntChild) Source).Value = int.Parse(val.ToString());
                break;
            case "BoolChild":
                ((BoolChild) Source).Value = bool.Parse(val.ToString());
                break;
            case "FloatChild":
                ((FloatChild) Source).Value = float.Parse(val.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot modify the BaseClass (I could only overwrite ToString()).

How can I replace the switch with a simpler line of code? I want to do something like the following

```
((Child) Source).Value = (val.GetType()) val;
```

,instead of the switch. Is this even possible?

Comment: Casting is a **compile-time**-operation. When you know the exact type only at **runtime**, you cannot cast - or at least not the way you want it.

Comment: Have you considered adding an abstract `SetValue` method to `BaseClass` which takes an `object` / `string` parameter? Then each class (e.g. `IntChild`) can have its own logic - rather than putting it in inside `MyProgram`. _If you don't have control over `BaseClass` add a new `abstract MiddleClass` which inherits from `BaseClass` and do what I suggested there instead (and change `Child` to inherit from `MiddleClass`)._

Comment: You could leverage C#7 pattern matching on type to clean up your switch statement a bit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements

Comment: I second mjwills with the suggestion to avoid switch by having several `SetValue( Type )` methods in `MiddleClass` . ( SetValue( int val ), SetValue( bool val ), ...)

Comment: I tried extending BaseClass through Child at first somehow, but I couldn't. Didn't think about the MiddleClass idea. Thanks!

Comment: `Source.GetType().GetProperty("Value").SetValue(Source, value)`?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov `Source.GetType()` returns type `Child`, which does not have a `Value` property (the `Value` is inside `Child<T>` only). So `GetProperty("Value")` returns null.
I clarify that IntChild is empty in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small variation of answer already provided by Slava Utesinov

```
   // Only set value if implementation of Child<>. 
   // If any other derived class of BaseClass with value field, then dont set 
   if(source.GetType().BaseType != null 
      && source.GetType().BaseType.IsGenericType 
      && source.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Child<>)) 
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Is implementation of Child<>");
       source.GetType().GetField("Value").SetValue(source, val);

   } 
   else 
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Not implementation of Child<>");
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the visitor pattern:

```
public abstract class BaseClassWithVisitor : BaseClass {
  void AcceptVisitor(BaseClassVisitor visitor);
}
```

This means `Child<T>` become abstract too.

Make all `Child<T>` children class implements `BaseClassWithVisitor.AcceptVisitor()` method, so they are not abstract:

```
public class IntChild : Child<int> {
   ...
   /// This method should be implemented in all Child<T> descendant classes
   public override void AcceptVisitor(BaseClassVisitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }
   ...
}
```

Then define the `BaseClassVisitor` interface :

```
public interface BaseClassVisitor {
    void Visit(IntChild intChild);
    void Visit(...); // all the other possible types
    ...
}
```

Then eventually create an implementation of the `BaseClassVisitor` that will do the operation you wanted:

```
public class SetValueVisitor : BaseClassVisitor {
    void Visit(IntChild intChild) { intChild.Value = 1; }
    void Visit(BoolChild boolChild) { boolChild.Value = false; }
    ...
}
```

Here is a complete example to make things clearer:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Visitor
{
    class BaseClass
    {
    }

    abstract class BaseClassWithVisitor : BaseClass
    {
        public abstract void AcceptVisitor(Visitor visitor);
    }

    abstract class Child<T> : BaseClassWithVisitor
    {
        public T Value;
    }

    class IntChild : Child<int>
    {
        public override void AcceptVisitor(Visitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }
    }
    class FloatChild : Child<float>
    {
        public override void AcceptVisitor(Visitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }
    }
    class StringChild : Child<string>
    {
        public override void AcceptVisitor(Visitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }
    }

    class Visitor
    {
        public object Value;

        public void Visit(IntChild intChild)
        {
            intChild.Value = int.Parse(Value.ToString());
        }
        public void Visit(FloatChild floatChild)
        {
            floatChild.Value = float.Parse(Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        public void Visit(StringChild stringChild)
        {
            stringChild.Value = Value.ToString();
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var visitor = new Visitor { Value = "12345" };
            var intChild = new IntChild();
            intChild.AcceptVisitor(visitor);

            visitor = new Visitor { Value = "1.2345" };
            var floatChild = new FloatChild();
            floatChild.AcceptVisitor(visitor);

            visitor = new Visitor { Value = "Hello World" };
            var stringChild = new StringChild();
            stringChild.AcceptVisitor(visitor);

            Console.WriteLine("intChild.Value    = {0}", intChild.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("floatChild.Value  = {0}", floatChild.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("stringChild.Value = {0}", stringChild.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
intChild.Value    = 12345
floatChild.Value  = 1,2345
stringChild.Value = Hello World
```

Comment: @Fildor I adressed the issue

Comment: Thanks. I got an error because `BaseClassWithVisitor` was not abstract. I made it abstract along with `Child<T>`. This solved the error, but of course I can't make an instance of `BaseClassWithVisitor` now.
Did I miss something, please?

Comment: As I said, you must implement the AcceptVisitor() methods in all the Child<T> classes. So they are not abstract. The implementation is always the same as I quoted in my answer.

Comment: @MGGD I updated the answer to better adress when classes are `abstract` and when classes are not abstract

Comment: I did that, but Child<T> itself still has to be abstract. I tried to use the visitor method with the original case in the question:
`BaseClassWithVisitor v;`
`v.AcceptVisitor(setValueVisitor); // v is not initialized`

Comment: Yes you cannot make an instance of `BaseClassWithVisitor` not `Child<T>` but you can make instance of `IntChild`, `BoolChild`, ...

Comment: The object I am trying to change its Value can be of type `BaseClass` or `BaseClassWithVisitor`.
How can I change it like this `MyObject.Value` or `MyObject.AcceptVisitor()` when it cannot be initialized ?
Sorry, this is my first time implementing this pattern and I am still trying to get it to work similar to the example in the original question.

Comment: I have added a complete example.

Comment: Thank you. It is more clear now. But it still doesn't solve the original example. Consider I have `BaseClass myChild`. At runtime, it will be assigned another variable (of type IntChild, FloatChild, ...etc).
Can the visitor pattern be used with `myChild` without altering the implementation of `BaseClass` ?

Comment: In that case, you have to use a cast like `(variable as BaseClassWithVisitor).AcceptVisitor(...)`. Obviously you have to only have instance of IntChild, FloatChild and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via reflection without classes modifying at all:

```
public void SetValue(object val)
{
    Source.GetType().GetProperty("Value").SetValue(Source, value);
}
```

Comment: `Source.GetType()` returns type `Child`, which does not have a `Value` property (the `Value` is inside `Child<T>` only). So `GetProperty("Value")` returns null. 
I clarify that IntChild is empty in my question.

Comment: @MGGD, Yes `IntChild` is empty but it inherits `Value` property from `Child<T>`

Comment: It worked as soon as I changed Value from variable to a property. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider:

```
public void SetValue(object val)
{
    dynamic dynamicSource = Source;
    dynamicSource.Value = val;
}
```

*It is a similar approach to the reflection based approaches, but a little more concise.*